# Prove or disprove $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f'(n)}{f(n)}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove or disprove the following:

> Let $f(x)$ be a differential function s,t $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ and $f'$ is positive.
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> $\sum_{n = k}^{\infty} \frac{f'(n)}{f(n)}$ diverge.

I have tried to prove it using the mean value theorem but didn't got me much further.

Any hints will be useful.

Comment: Hint: Try to create such a function with $f'(n)=0$ for all integer $n$.

Comment: @Balloon $f'$ have to be positive, I forgot that sorry.

Comment: What does $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ mean? Do you mean $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$? Also does $f$ have to be defined on all $\mathbb{R}$ or can $f$ be something like $\tan x$ which is undefined as countably many points.

Comment: Doesn't this diverge by the integral test with $u$-substitution $u = f(x)$?

Comment: @Gregory Integral test assumes $\frac{f}{f'}$ is positive and decreasing w.r.t n.

Comment: We have both types of examples for which $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} f'(n)/f(n)$ converges and diverges, respectively. It requires a bit of work to carve out such examples. However, the main idea is that, starting from a reasonable nice function $f_0$ (such as $f_0(x) = x$), you can modify $f_0'$ around integer points to obtain a new function $f$ so that $f'(n)$ takes the values you wish but the overall growth behavior of $f(x)$ is almost the same as that of $f_0(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapting the hint that @Balloon gave, the idea that I arrived at was to select $f(x)$ which satisfies the given conditions and which has $\frac{f'(n)}{f(n)} < r^n$ for some $0 < r <1$. I first used an online graphing calculator to verify that this function satisfies all of the conditions given. The analysis of the function can be seen below.

Let $f(x) = - e^{-x} + 2\pi x - \sin(2\pi x) $
with derivative $f'(x) =e^{-x} + 2\pi - 2\pi \cos(2\pi x)$. It is straightforward to show that
$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ and that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$.In fact, since $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and tending towards infinity we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f'(n)}{f(n)} <
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f'(n)}{f(1)} &=
\frac{1}{2\pi-e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\pi - 2\pi \cos(2\pi n) + e^{-n} \\&=
\frac{1}{2\pi-e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n} \\&=
\frac{1}{2\pi-e}\left( \frac{e}{1-e} \right).
\end{align}
Therefore the series converges.